# avoid circular dependency on hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name="MEDICAL_DEVICE")
public class MedicalDevice {

    public MedicalDevice(UUID deviceId, DefectPriority defectPriority, State currentState) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.defectPriority = defectPriority;
        this.currentState = currentState;
    }

    public MedicalDevice(UUID deviceId, State currentState) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.currentState = currentState;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="DEVICE_ID")
    @NotNull
    private UUID deviceId;

    @Column(name="DEFECT_PRIORITY", nullable = true)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DefectPriority defectPriority;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="medicalDevice")
    private List<State> states = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="medicalDevice")
    private State currentState;



}
```

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name="STATE")
public class State {

    public State(StateNames state, UUID enteredBy, LocalDateTime enteredAt) {
        this.state = state;
        this.enteredBy = enteredBy;
        this.enteredAt = enteredAt;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StateNames state;

    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private UUID enteredBy;       //User who changed the devices state to this one

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="MEDICAL_DEVICE_ID")
    @NotNull
    private MedicalDevice medicalDevice;



    @Column(name = "LOCAL_DATE_TIME", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime enteredAt;    //Time when the devices state was changed into this one

    @Column(name = "LOCAL_DATE", columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate availabilityDate; //Date when a device will be available (only used in defect states and bought state)

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="state")
    private List<AdditionalInformation> additionalInformation;


}
```

how to avoid circular dependency on hibernate between State class and MedicalDevice class? I have implemented @OneToMany List which is the old states and @OneToOne State currentState which indicates the current state. I would like to have it separate not all in the list but my implementation causes that>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MtnI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate MedicalAdvice object inside your State class with `@JsonIgnore` annotation. This way, you can prevent infinite recursive fetching of data from relationships between entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide the error message so it's hard to know exactly what's causing the circular dependency, but the basic idea is that it stems from the fact that `MedicalDevice` has a reference to `State` and vice versa, so each rely on the other.

(Incidentally, you also have `MedicalDevice` set up to have a list of `State` with a @OneToMany relationship, and one instance of `State` with a @OneToOne relationship. That doesn't really work, either it's a @OneToMany or it's @OneToOne. Put another way, either `MedicalDevice` has one `State` or it has many `State`s, but it doesn't have both. I don't know if that is contributing to your problem).

In any event, it's possible the circular dependency is due to either the equals/hashcode being called, or perhaps the toString method. `MedicalDevice` maybe calling these methods on its `State` variable, which in turn will call the method on its `MedicalDevice` variable, etc.

A possible resolution would be to exclude the references from the equals/hashcode and toString methods. But again, without the details of the error it hard to tell what the exact issue is.

Comment: There is no error. It works fine but when i call the api , i get this circular